# How do I use(ActionScript 3) RegEx to match a tag with optional attributes, one specific attribute/value, and preserve its contents?

Tags: regex, actionscript

I am not new to regex but have come across a problem I can't seem to solve. I'm trying to locate a specific HTML tag that has a specific attribute/value pair (it may have other attributes, too, but those are optional), extract it's contents as a backreference and wrap a new custom tag around it. The original tag is:

```
<p backgroundColor="#0066cc" color="#0066cc" lineHeight="18" paragraphSpaceAfter="15" paragraphSpaceBefore="15" fontSize="24">This is my second paragraph, with some <span fontStyle="italic">inline stuff</span>too.</p>
```

I'd like to get it to be:

```
<custom_heading>This is my second paragraph, with some <span fontStyle="italic">inline stuff</span>too.</custom_heading>
```

The expression I'm currently using is this:

```
r = new RegExp("<p[^<]*backgroundColor=\"#0066cc\"[^>?]*\>","gi");
            s=s.replace(r,"<bwt_heading>");
```

This works fine (replacing only the opening tag) until I then try and add the content, and closing tag:

```
<p[^<]*backgroundColor=\"#0066cc\"[^>?]*\>(.*?)</p>
```

The above results in no match, no replacement at all. Please help! I have managed to replace several other tags (and preserve their contents via backreference, like so:

```
<span>
```

Comment: I tweaked the formatting, but the question seems to be incomplete.  Did you hit "Send" by accident or something?

Answer (score 0):

If the short regex works, the long one should, too--unless there are newlines between the `<p>` and `</p>`.  Have you tried it with `([\s\S]*?)` instead of `(.*?)`?

Also, you've got `[^<]*` and `[^>?]*` in your original regex, neither of which seems right.  I suspect they should both be `[^>]*`.

---

EDIT: It [appears](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html#dotall) AS3 supports the `s` modifier for *dotall* mode (a.k.a. *single-line* or *dot-matches-newlines* mode), which is nice.  ActionScript supposedly implements the ECMAScript standard, which (as of version 3) does not support a *dotall* mode, necessitating the `[\s\S]` hack we all know and love from JavaScript regexes.

That being the case, your *regex* doesn't need to be changed at all:

```
r = new RegExp("<p[^>]*backgroundColor=\"#0066cc\"[^>]*>(.*?)</p>","gis");
s=s.replace(r,"<bwt_heading>$1</bwt_heading>");
```